# Physicaloid library Arduino + Android

Tags: java, android, arduino, serial

Никак не могу разобраться как создать цикл чтения Serial Monitor'a при помощи библиотеки Physicaloid library. А выход из этого цикла должен совершаться только тогда, когда в serial появится слово "end". 
Пытался сделать это так:

```
mPhys = new Physicaloid(this);

public onClick(View v) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    int readSize = 0;

    while (true) {
        readSize = mPhys.read(buf);  //чтение serial

        if (readSize > 0) {
            strData = new String(buf); // переменная хранящая данные с serial
        }
            if (Objects.equals(strData, "end")) {
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, причина в том, что при вставке курсор соскочил на другую строку. Должно быть так, наверное:

```
    if (readSize > 0) {
        strData = new String(buf); // переменная хранящая данные с serial
        if (Objects.equals(strData, "end")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```